# How to delete the file from the FTP using Proxy in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ftp, http-proxy

I have some problem in my project. I want to delete my file from the ftp using proxy.

My code is:

```
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + FtpServerName + FtpFilePath);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;


                request.Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyAddress);
                request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUserName,     ProxyPassword);

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

In this i'm getting error like:
The requested FTP Command is not supported when using http proxy

can any one please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please reply as soon as possible. its very urgent.

Comment: Your code shows the file delete attempt before you started wth the proxy.  Perhaps you shold show us the working code showing that you can connect with the proxy and view files, and check the file you want was there before you try delete it

Comment: I tried that option also.But still i'm getting the same error

Comment: tried what? I want to see the code that you used to check the directory listing through the proxy and show that you can make proper connection with it, and then worry about deleting the file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2004/09/13/229069.aspx:

> Note on using Http Proxy on FTPWebRequest: Http proxy is only supported for limited number of ftp methods (mainly to download file only), so if you have IE settings for proxy on your machine you need to explicitly set FtpWebRequest to not use proxy like below
>
> request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();

If you want to perform other FTP actions through a proxy, you'll have to find another FTP component that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();`

try `request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;`

Follows a demo code that worked well for me:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://99.999.99.99/TextFile1.txt"));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftp_user", "ftp_pass"); // it's FTP credentials, not proxy
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

var sourceStream = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt");
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();
```